# Identifying and counting duplicate IDs by date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to count duplicate IDs by day in a data set. I am pretty new to R and I am struggling.

An example of the dataset (apologies for the junky tables):

```
  Date   ID1  ID2  ID3  ID4  ID5 

 1/8/10  BL   LD   AB   AR   UB  

 1/8/10  GG   BL   BH   QR   ZB  

 1/9/10  BF   GO
```

I need it to tell me something like:

```
Date   Duplicate ID    Count 
1/8/10     BL              2
```

I have been trying to use `dplyr` for this but maybe the code is not specific enough:

This code returns the error below:

```
data %>%
   group_by(date_time) %>% filter(duplicated)
```

> Error: Argument 2 filter condition does not evaluate to a logical vector

Nothing seems to happen with this code:

```
data %>% group_by(date_time) %>% mutate(Repeats = row_number()-1)
```

If anyone has any ideas on how to help with this, I really appreciate it!

Comment: Hey! If you have trouble generating a reproducible example, you can easily do that by pasting the output of `dput(your_data)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that by using tidyr gather and then summarizing the data to get the IDs that are repeated as follows;

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <-
  data.frame(
    Date = c("1/8/10", "1/8/10", "1/9/10"),
    ID1 = c("BL", "GG", "BF"),
    ID2 = c("LD", "BL", "GO"),
    ID3 = c("AB", "BH", NA),
    ID4 = c("AR", "QR", NA),
    ID5 = c("UB", "ZB", NA),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
  )

data %>%
  gather(key = "holder", value = "ID", - Date) %>%
  filter(!is.na(ID)) %>%
  group_by(Date, ID) %>%
  count() %>%
  filter(n >= 2) %>%
  rename(Duplicate_ID = ID,
         Count = n)

# # A tibble: 1 x 3
# # Groups:   Date, Duplicate_ID [1]
# Date   Duplicate_ID Count
# <chr>  <chr>        <int>
#   1/8/10 BL               2
```

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you should update your example

```
library(tidyverse)

df_example <- tribble(~Date,~ID1,~ID2,~ID3,~ID4,~ID5,
        '1/8/10', 'BL', 'LD', 'AB', 'AR', 'UB', 
        '1/8/10', 'GG', 'BL', 'BH', 'QR', 'ZB', 
        '1/9/10', 'BF', 'GO', 'BL', 'AB', 'UB', 
        '1/8/10', 'GG', 'BL', 'BH', 'QR', 'ZB')

df_example %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = -Date) %>% 
  group_by(Date,name) %>% 
  tally() %>% 
  filter(n > 1)
```